# Populate child tables from an xml column

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008

I have xml that looks something like this, stored in a table, Files:

```
<file>
    <collections>
        <collection>
            <date>1-1-2017</date>
            <codes>
                 <identifier>A</identifier>
                 <date>A</date>
            </codes>
        </collection>
        ...More collections here
    </collections>
</file>
```

If I have tables set up like:

```
Files
ID    xmlData

Files_Collections
ID    Files_ID   date 

Collections_codes
ID  Files_Collections_ID    identifier    date
```

Is there a way to query from Files > xmlData into the two child tables where it populates the child tables in a way that properly indexes the foreign keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: **never ever use culture dependant date formats!** Your `1-1-2017` will be a `2-3-2017` somewhere else. Is it the second of March or the third of February? Always use ISO8601 within XML. In your case `2017-01-01` (`YYYY-MM-DD`)

Try this

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<file>
    <collections>
        <collection>
            <date>2017-01-01</date>
            <codes>
                 <identifier>A</identifier>
                 <date>A</date>
            </codes>
        </collection>
        <collection>
            <date>2017-02-03</date>
            <codes>
                 <identifier>B</identifier>
                 <date>B</date>
            </codes>
        </collection>
    </collections>
</file>';
```

--the query

```
WITH files AS
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS FileId
           ,Fl.query('.') AS xmlData
    FROM @xml.nodes(N'/file') AS A(Fl)
)
,collections AS
(
    SELECT files.FileId
          ,files.xmlData
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS CollectionId
          ,col.value(N'(date/text())[1]',N'date') AS CollectionDate
          ,col.query(N'codes') AS optionXml
    FROM files
    OUTER APPLY files.xmlData.nodes(N'/file/collections/collection') AS A(col)
)
SELECT   collections.FileId
        ,collections.xmlData
        ,collections.CollectionId
        ,collections.CollectionDate
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS CodeId
        ,col.value(N'(identifier/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS CodeIdentifier
        ,col.value(N'(date/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS CodeDate
FROM collections
OUTER APPLY collections.optionXml.nodes(N'/codes') AS A(col);
```

Write this into a temp table and use `SELECT DISTINCT` to insert each set of data together with the appropriate foreign key into its table.

Comment: I appreciate the advice regarding the format but it isn't my xml. Regardless, this is a good answer thank you.